# Legacy links rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to rewrite:

```
index.php?node=[something]
```

to

```
/node/[something]
```

(the "node" part will be static text and it's not important)

i've tried:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php?node=(.*)$ /node/$1 [L,R=301]
```

(again the rewritten "node" part will be static text and it's not important)

and a lot of other variations without success...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) to examine the query as it’s not part of the URL path:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(([^&]*&+)*)node=([^&]*)(&.*)?
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /node/%3?%1%4 [L,R=301]
```